# HTML5 Sortable jQuery Plugin don't work on ipad

Tags: jquery, html, ipad, plugins, jquery-ui-sortable

i use HTML5 Sortable jQuery Plugin( http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable/ ) and it works on my computer(Google chrome, etc). i use mouse and ther is not any problem. But it dont work on ipad. In touch devices dont sense dragable items. if you can help me i will be happy.

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.shuffle.js"></script>
<script language="javascript1.5">
    function kontrolet()
    {
        var id;
        var say=0;
        for(a=0;a<dizi.length;a++)
        {
            id = $('ul.sortable li:nth-child('+(a+1)+')').attr("id");
            if(a!=id) say++; 
        }
        if(say==0) alert("İt's true");
        else
        alert("Ther are "+ say +" wrong!!!");
    }           

var dizi=new Array(1,4,5,8,10,13,14,15);

$(document).ready(function(){   
for(a=0;a<dizi.length;a++)
$('ul').append('<li id='+a+'><img src="'+dizi[a]+'.jpg" width="100%"/></li>');
}); 
</script>
    <ul class="sortable grid" style="margin-left:3%;"></ul>
```

Comment: I don't think you can "drag" in iPad. `:P`

Comment: if you can use mouse pointer it's work. But touchscreen dont make drag process

Comment: Yup... That's what I meant...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download/link touch-punch.js for the draggable functionality within Ipad devices.

http://touchpunch.furf.com/

Comment: thanks your help. İf i can this ".js " i must change all code and i must make sortable. Does not This code block   make on ipad ?

Comment: You shouldn't have to change any code, it simply uses the same sortable()/draggable methods you are currently using.